# I need a formula for how many ways I can choose $k$ balls (two balls each time from the same box) from $n$ boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

We have $n$ (can take any value $1,2,3,...$) boxes each has the same number of distinct marbles, say $b$ marbles, so the total number of marbles $S=n*b$. We can choose marbles from boxes with the following conditions:

1- The marbles in each box are divided into equal subsets each with size $k$ (can take any value, , the sample case when $k=1$), so each box contains $\frac {b}{k}$ subsets, and there is a total of $\frac {n*b}{k}$ subsets in all available boxes. note that k is integer only $(1\le k\le b)$

2-  Marbles only can be chosen as subsets not individuals.

3- we can choose any number of subsets $m$, each has a size $k$.

We want a general formula for the number of combinations of choosing any number of the marbles subsets from the available boxes.
As example for the sample case: subset size k=1, then the solution will be $S=\binom {n*b}{m*k}$

I want a formula for the other cases such as: $3$ boxes $(n=3)$ each has $9$ distinct marbles $(b=9)$, the subset size $k=3$, so the number of available subsets in each box will be $\frac {9}{3}=3$ subsets (total $9$ subsets in the $3$ boxes), what the number of possible ways to choose $4$ subsets each with size $k=3 (m=4)$?

Comment: Before answering the genral question, I need to understand why you think the answer in the example is $12$. The actual number is $6\cdot 6$, not $6+6$.

Comment: From your example, the balls appear to be *distinct*. Does each box contain the same number of balls?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to answer the above questions, and also explain what happens for larger values of k, e.g. k=4?  (E.g. is choosing {a,b} then {c,d} the same as choosing {c,d} then {a,b}; is it the same as choosing {a,c} then {b,d}?)  I'm worried that your question will attract answers that take a "best guess" at what the question means.

Comment: For **every one** of the $6$ choices you have from the first box, you have $6$ choices for what you take from the second box, so we need to take the **product**, not the sum. You have not answered the quesition of whether each box has the same number of balls. If they do, the answer is quite simple. If they don't, it is significantly messier.

Comment: Is this the question?:  Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a partition of a set $X$ into $n$ parts of size $b$.  How many $k$-subsets $S \subseteq X$ are there such that $|S \cap X_i|$ is even for all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Since we are choosing $2$ balls from each box, the number $k$ must be even. It is convenient to let $k=2m$.

It has been indicated in a comment that each box has the same number of balls, say $b$ balls.

There are $\binom{n}{m}$ ways to select the boxes we will take two balls each from.

For **each** way of selecting the boxes, we can choose $2$ balls from any of the selected boxes in  $\binom{b}{2}$ ways. It follows that the total number of choices is
$$\binom{n}{m}\binom{b}{2}^m.$$

**Remark:** Suppose we are choosing $2$ balls each from particular boxes, say boxes A, B, and C. There are $\binom{b}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ balls from box A. For **every** choice of balls from box A, there are $\binom{b}{2}$ ways to select $2$ balls from box B. Thus the number of ways to choose from A **and** B is $\binom{b}{2}\binom{b}{2}$ (we *multioply*). For **every** way of choosing $2$ balls from A and $2$ from B, there are $\binom{b}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ balls from C. So the number of ways to select $2$ balls from *each* of A, B, and C is $\binom{b}{2}^3$.

**Added:** The above formula counts the number of ways to choose a total of $k$ balls, where for any one of the $n$ boxes, exactly $2$ balls are chosen from that box, or $0$ balls are chosen from that box.

There are many other questions one could ask, with roughly similar wording. In order to make it possible to give a precise answer to such similar-sounding questions, the choosing rule has to be stated exactly.

Comment: But the OP's comment indicates it's possible to repeatedly select from the same box (in the "(12,34)" and "(ab,cd)" examples).

Comment: We have $n$ boxes. Each has $b$ marbles. All marbles are distinct. We want to choose $k=2m$ marbles. From any box, we can either take exactly $2$ marbles or exactly $0$. In all your examples, we had $m=n$, meaning we took $2$ marbles from every box, but the formula I gave is more general. By the way, the system objects to long strings of comments. I will delete most of mine, suggest you do the same. But you can continue to ask questions!

Comment: With $6$ marbles from **two** boxes, the situation is different, and **not** covered by the formula. The formula deals only with situations where we are choosing $2$ (or $0$) from each box. If you still want an **even** number from each box, then we choose all from the first box, and $2$ from the other or the other way around. Then the answer is $\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{2}=12$.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to say, (But my English is not good). I want a general formula for any even number of marbles available in both boxes (0, 2, 4, 6, or 8) for the example I give.

Comment: For very general problems of this type, generating functions might be useful. If you want an answer, the problem should at first be broad enough for the answer to be useful to you, and narrow enough to have a chance of a solution. I urge that if you ask a question, it be absolutely clear.

Comment: I think my problem is clear now

Comment: I looked to see whether the question has changed, and it does not seem to have. What you are asking is not clear to me.

Comment: The question is reedited

Comment: Any answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Your question still leaves a few things unclear, starting with why there are boxes in the first place. The answer you gave for $k=1$ suggests that you can choose as many subsets as you want from any of the boxes; but then the boxes play no role in the calculation, i.e. all the subsets could just be in one box without changing the answer. For the remainder of what I'm writing I'm going to assume that that's the case; if not, you need to clarify what restrictions there are for choosing from each box.

The other confusion is how to treat the subsets you refer to; are they fixed, or are you counting over all possible combinations of marbles within the subsets? To be more clear about what I'm asking, suppose that $k=3$, and that one subset consists of the three distinct marbles $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$. Are you (call this Option 1) counting only the cases where those three marbles are always in the same subset, or does your count include the cases where those three marbles might be in different subsets? If it's the latter, then there's another question that needs answering: do you care about which marbles you end up with, or which subsets? Again as an example, if in one instance you chose the two subsets $\{ \alpha, \beta, \gamma \}$ and $\{ \delta, \epsilon, \zeta \}$, and in another instance you chose the subsets $\{ \alpha, \epsilon, \gamma \}$ and $\{ \delta, \beta, \zeta \}$, would you consider those as (Option 2) the same case or (Option 3) different cases?

Option 1: in this case the marbles themselves have no role in the calculation; you're just counting the number of ways to choose subsets. Then the number of ways to choose would be

$$\binom{\frac{n \cdot b}{k}}{m}$$

Option 2: in this case the subsets have no role in the count, you're just counting the number of ways to choose an amount of marbles which is a multiple of $k$. Under these circumstances the number of ways to choose would be

$$\binom {n \cdot b}{m \cdot k}$$

Option 3: finally, in this case, in addition to the count from Option 2, you need to count how many ways the $m \cdot k$ chosen marbles can be partitioned into $m$ unordered sets of size $k$. To do that, we first assume the sets are ordered, then we can distribute the marbles to the sets in

$$\binom{m \cdot k}{\underbrace{ k! \cdot k! \cdot k! \cdot \ldots \cdot k! }_{m \; \text{times}}} = \frac{(m \cdot k)!}{(k!)^m}$$

but then we have to divide that by $m!$ since we don't want the sets to be ordered. Thus in this final case the count would be

$$\binom {n \cdot b}{m \cdot k} \cdot \frac{(m \cdot k)!}{(k!)^m \cdot m!}$$